# Write an anonymous sub in Perl to a file for later use

Tags: perl, hash, functional-programming, generative-programming

I have a Perl program that generates parsing rules as subs from an input file.  The subs are anonymously defined an put into a hash.  Now, I want to export that hash, with all the subs and then load them again later to use with a different program.

How do I go about doing this?  Is there some way to extract the code of each sub, or can I copy the block of memory that the hash exists in and then cast it as a hash when I load it again later?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of saving the actual compiled subs, you could save the *text* of the subs, and then re-eval them into coderefs in the new process.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that.  But I would like to be able to save the compiled subs for aesthetic reasons. :-p

Comment: All techniques I know of use B::Deparse to translate the code reference back into Perl source code.  This process may not give you back the same source code that you started with.  I do not think this will buy you much over simply saving the actual original text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the ["Code References"](http://search.cpan.org/~ams/Storable-2.21/Storable.pm#CODE_REFERENCES) section of the Storable documentation (with added emphasis):

> Since Storable version 2.05, CODE references may be serialized with the help of `B::Deparse`. To enable this feature, set `$Storable::Deparse` to a true value. To enable deserialization, `$Storable::Eval` should be set to a true value. **Be aware that deserialization is done through `eval`, which is dangerous if the Storable file contains malicious data.**

In the demo below, a child process creates the hash of anonymous subs. Then the parent—in an entirely separate process and address space, so it can't see `%dispatch`—reads the output from `freeze` in the same way that you might from a file on disk.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Storable qw/ freeze thaw /;

my $pid = open my $fh, "-|";
die "$0: fork: $!" unless defined $pid;

if ($pid == 0) {
  # child process
  my %dispatch = (
    foo => sub { print "Yo!\n" },
    bar => sub { print "Hi!\n" },
    baz => sub { print "Holla!\n" },
  );

  local $Storable::Deparse = 1 || $Storable::Deparse;
  binmode STDOUT, ":bytes";
  print freeze \%dispatch;
  exit 0;
}
else {
  # parent process
  local $/;
  binmode $fh, ":bytes";
  my $frozen = <$fh>;

  local $Storable::Eval = 1 || $Storable::Eval;
  my $d = thaw $frozen;
  $d->{$_}() for keys %$d;
}
```

Output:

```
Hi!
Holla!
Yo!
```

Comment: and I can simply write `$frozen` to a text file? and don't worry, I will sanitize my inputs.  I learned this from XKCD :D

Comment: @Mechko Yes, in your code, you'd write the output to a file on disk and then read it in later. I changed the demo to resemble what both sides of your pipeline might look like.

Answer (score 4):

[KiokuDB](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?KiokuDB) can handle storing code references in addition to other Perl types.  So can the various [YAML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?YAML::XS) modules, [Data::Dump::Streamer](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data::Dump::Streamer), and even Data::Dumper.